# How to get a graph with the k most important features from my model?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

Hello I am working with random forest with several matrix, I would like to get just the k best features of my model,

I mean just the 3, 4 or the k features with more relevance in my model I tried as follows:

However the problem with this approach is that I am getting the plot of all my features and since I am computing a lot 
this is not so interpretable as I wish, thus I would like to appreciate support to modify the above code to just get a graph of a fixed number 
of features, I would like to fix it as a parameter,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_matrix = np.concatenate([state_matrix,company_matrix,seg,complete_work,sub_rep,b_tec,time1,time2,time3,time4,time5,len1], axis=1)

#Performing a shuffle of my data
index_list = list(range(train_matrix.shape[0]))
random.shuffle(index_list)
train_matrix= train_matrix[index_list]
labels_list= labels_list[index_list]

print('times shape: ', time_matrix.shape)
print('cities shape: ', cities.shape)
print('labels1 shape: ', labels1.shape)
print('state shape: ', state_matrix.shape)
print('work type shape: ', work_type.shape)
print('train matrix shape', train_matrix.shape)
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import preprocessing
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    train_matrix, labels_list.tolist(), test_size=0.1, random_state=47)

clf2 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,n_jobs=4)

print("vectorization completed")
print("begining training")
import timeit
start_time = timeit.default_timer()

clf2 = clf2.fit(X_train, y_train)
elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time

print('Matrix time shape: '+str(train_matrix.shape)+' Time Seconds: ',elapsed)

#with open('random_forest.pickle','wb') as idxf:
#    pickle.dump(clf2, idxf, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
print("finishing training")

y_pred = clf2.predict(X_test)
```

Here is the part that I would like to modify in order to get just the k best values of my model:

```
importances = clf2.feature_importances_
std = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in clf2.estimators_],
             axis=0)
indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]

# Print the feature ranking
print("Feature ranking:")

for f in range(X_train.shape[1]):
    print("%d. feature %d (%f)" % (f + 1, indices[f], importances[indices[f]]))

#Plot the feature importances of the forest
plt.figure()
plt.title("Feature importances")
plt.bar(range(X_train.shape[1]), importances[indices],
       color="r", yerr=std[indices], align="center")
plt.xticks(range(X_train.shape[1]), indices)
plt.xlim([-1, X_train.shape[1]])
plt.savefig('fig1.png', dpi = 600)

plt.show()
```

This is other part of code:

```
print("PREDICTION REPORT")
# importing Confusion Matrix and recall
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

print(precision_recall_fscore_support(y_test, y_pred, average='macro'))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))

# to print unique values
print(set(y_test))
print(set(y_pred))

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))


Output:

Feature ranking:
1. feature 660 (0.403711)
2. feature 655 (0.139531)
3. feature 659 (0.058074)
4. feature 658 (0.057855)
5. feature 321 (0.015031)
6. feature 322 (0.012731)
7. feature 324 (0.011937)
8. feature 336 (0.011728)
9. feature 650 (0.011174)
10. feature 656 (0.010441)
11. feature 657 (0.009340)
12. feature 337 (0.007385)
13. feature 509 (0.005184)
14. feature 330 (0.005056)
15. feature 325 (0.004927)
16. feature 344 (0.004891)
17. feature 326 (0.004495)
18. feature 334 (0.004349)
19. feature 333 (0.004291)
20. feature 352 (0.004284)
21. feature 338 (0.004164)
22. feature 285 (0.003909)
23. feature 345 (0.003631)
24. feature 652 (0.003341)
25. feature 329 (0.003168)
26. feature 651 (0.002890)
27. feature 388 (0.002680)
28. feature 146 (0.002650)
29. feature 332 (0.002482)
30. feature 217 (0.002475)
31. feature 513 (0.002363)
32. feature 216 (0.002309)
33. feature 116 (0.002223)
34. feature 323 (0.002107)
35. feature 213 (0.002104)
36. feature 328 (0.002101)
37. feature 102 (0.002088)
38. feature 315 (0.002083)
39. feature 307 (0.002079)
40. feature 427 (0.002043)
41. feature 351 (0.001925)
42. feature 259 (0.001888)
43. feature 171 (0.001878)
44. feature 243 (0.001863)
45. feature 78 (0.001862)
46. feature 490 (0.001815)
47. feature 339 (0.001770)
48. feature 103 (0.001767)
49. feature 591 (0.001741)
50. feature 55 (0.001734)
51. feature 502 (0.001665)
52. feature 194 (0.001632)
53. feature 491 (0.001625)
54. feature 50 (0.001591)
55. feature 193 (0.001590)
56. feature 97 (0.001549)
57. feature 510 (0.001514)
58. feature 245 (0.001504)
59. feature 434 (0.001497)
60. feature 8 (0.001468)
61. feature 241 (0.001457)
62. feature 108 (0.001454)
63. feature 232 (0.001453)
64. feature 292 (0.001443)
65. feature 96 (0.001434)
66. feature 99 (0.001381)
67. feature 11 (0.001367)
68. feature 106 (0.001360)
69. feature 592 (0.001335)
70. feature 60 (0.001334)
71. feature 523 (0.001327)
72. feature 72 (0.001324)
73. feature 236 (0.001323)
74. feature 128 (0.001320)
75. feature 144 (0.001318)
76. feature 288 (0.001300)
77. feature 238 (0.001292)
78. feature 654 (0.001287)
79. feature 499 (0.001285)
80. feature 223 (0.001283)
81. feature 593 (0.001275)
82. feature 33 (0.001264)
83. feature 289 (0.001240)
84. feature 94 (0.001236)
85. feature 433 (0.001233)
86. feature 129 (0.001227)
87. feature 437 (0.001226)
88. feature 113 (0.001221)
89. feature 54 (0.001220)
90. feature 271 (0.001213)
91. feature 107 (0.001186)
92. feature 562 (0.001165)
93. feature 488 (0.001144)
94. feature 521 (0.001128)
95. feature 269 (0.001110)
96. feature 313 (0.001102)
97. feature 13 (0.001063)
98. feature 59 (0.001059)
99. feature 529 (0.001059)
100. feature 278 (0.001055)
101. feature 68 (0.001053)
102. feature 189 (0.001038)
103. feature 176 (0.001001)
104. feature 367 (0.001000)
105. feature 32 (0.001000)
106. feature 18 (0.000984)
107. feature 135 (0.000957)
108. feature 127 (0.000933)
109. feature 39 (0.000924)
110. feature 391 (0.000921)
111. feature 156 (0.000919)
112. feature 316 (0.000904)
113. feature 389 (0.000895)
114. feature 522 (0.000885)
115. feature 449 (0.000874)
116. feature 4 (0.000872)
117. feature 258 (0.000840)
118. feature 489 (0.000828)
119. feature 347 (0.000823)
120. feature 264 (0.000790)
```

After a feedback from here I tried:

```
importances = clf2.feature_importances_
std = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in clf2.estimators_],
             axis=0)

indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]
top_k = 10
new_indices = indices[:top_k]
#So you just need to change this part accordingly (just change top_k to your desired value):

# Print the feature ranking
print("Feature ranking:")

for f in range(top_k):
    print("%d. feature %d (%f)" % (f + 1, new_indices[f], importances[new_indices[f]]))
#Same here for plotting the graph:

#Plot the feature importances of the forest
plt.figure()
plt.title("Feature importances")
plt.bar(range(top_k), importances[new_indices],
       color="r", yerr=std[new_indices], align="center")

    importances = clf2.feature_importances_
std = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in clf2.estimators_],
             axis=0)

indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]
top_k = 10
new_indices = indices[:top_k]
#So you just need to change this part accordingly (just change top_k to your desired value):

# Print the feature ranking
print("Feature ranking:")

for f in range(top_k):
    print("%d. feature %d (%f)" % (f + 1, new_indices[f], importances[new_indices[f]]))
#Same here for plotting the graph:

#Plot the feature importances of the forest
plt.figure()
plt.title("Feature importances")
plt.bar(range(top_k), importances[new_indices],
       color="r", yerr=std[new_indices], align="center")


plt.xticks(range(new_indices), new_indices)
plt.xlim([-1, new_indices])
plt.savefig('fig1.png', dpi = 600)
plt.show()
plt.xticks(range(new_indices), new_indices)
plt.xlim([-1, new_indices])
plt.savefig('fig1.png', dpi = 600)
plt.show()
```

However I got, the following error so I really appreciate support to overcome this task.

```
Feature ranking:
1. feature 660 (0.405876)
2. feature 655 (0.138400)
3. feature 659 (0.056848)
4. feature 658 (0.056631)
5. feature 321 (0.014537)
6. feature 336 (0.013202)
7. feature 324 (0.012455)
8. feature 322 (0.011517)
9. feature 656 (0.011493)
10. feature 650 (0.010850)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "random_forest.py", line 234, in <module>
    plt.xticks(range(new_indices), new_indices)
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: you can use slicing on your middle code part to get the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where the the indices of important features are arranged in decreasing order. That means using indices[:10] will get you top 10 features.

```
indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]
top_k = 10
new_indices = indices[:top_k]
```

So you just need to change this part accordingly (just change `top_k` to your desired value):

```
# Print the feature ranking
print("Feature ranking:")

for f in range(top_k):
    print("%d. feature %d (%f)" % (f + 1, new_indices[f], importances[new_indices[f]]))
```

Same here for plotting the graph:

```
#Plot the feature importances of the forest
plt.figure()
plt.title("Feature importances")
plt.bar(range(top_k), importances[new_indices],
       color="r", yerr=std[new_indices], align="center")

#Edited here (put top_k in range)
plt.xticks(range(top_k), new_indices)
#Edited here (put top_k)
plt.xlim([-1, top_k])
plt.show()
```

Comment: @neo33 I have edited my code to solve the issue. It was a mistake on my side. I had put array in place of an integer. I have solved it now. And marked in code what i changed